# Slow start of Serial Communication With Arduino and Python

Tags: python, performance, arduino, serial-communication

So I am using an Arduino Uno and pySerial to communicate with a PC using serial communication. My program is working, and once it initializes, it appears to work fast; however, it takes the Arduino several seconds to begin acting on the code. I would not have a huge problem with this slow start, except it appears to put the rest of the code behind (When I exit the program, the motors on my arduino keep running for several seconds).

If a variable I am using changes (chosen by the user), I want the Serial communication to immediately send the information to arduino and the arduino to act differently given the variable change, and I am concerned that it will not act immediatly.

One thing which might be slowing down the initialization is this code:

Arduino:

```
void establishContact()
{
   while (Serial.available()<=0) 
   {
    Serial.print('A');
    delay(300);
   }
}
```

Python:

```
firstContact = False 
inByte = ser.read(1)

while True:
    if (firstContact == False):
        if inByte == b'A' :
            firstContact = True
            ser.write('a'.encode())
```

I used this to save time by not sending bytes on either side if one of the programs, Arduino or Python, is not ready to receive information. (This was previously suggested to speed up run time, though I can't remember from who or where I read it.) Is this slowing down my program or would you say it is useful?

Another potential way to speed up my code (though I am again not sure if it will slow down or speed up) is to check (after each time I have sent information) on each side whether the arduino is ready to again receive information, so that the arduino is not overloaded with information, which could slow it down. (I believe my Python code is sending commands faster than the Arduino is enacting them.)

I am using 9600 baud rate, would using a higher one help?

I also have several embeded if-elif-elif statements in my Python code, which I understand often slows code, but I have not been able to figure out a suitable replacement, and it also doesn't appear to be too much of a problem on the Python side.

Would clearing the serial buffer help? The reason I ask this is because if I could work it correctly on the Arduino side, it could get rid of the build up of commands from Python, so even if the program initializes slowly, both programs are running synchronously, in real time.

These are all suggestions I have picked up in different places, though I am not sure if they will help in my specific case. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What are the units of the delay() function on the Arduino EstablishContact function? Are you sure?

Comment: @barny The units are milliseconds, and I'm about 95% sure of that, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: When using serial for serious arduino project I usually use baudrate of 57600. Try a pySerial wrapper for arduino like [pyFirmata](https://github.com/tino/pyfirmata) or [pluto](https://github.com/jochasinga/pluto). The latter one is under development and used only for testing/prototyping.

Comment: @pie-o-pah Sorry, just to make sure I understand, because I had a hard time understanding from the literature I found online about the linked wrappers, do you essentially use pyFirmata as a replacement for pySerial, as a serial communication between a microcontroller (Arduino) and code (python) on the computer?

Comment: pyFirmata simply inherits some properties of pySerial and implement Firmata protocol to interface with microcontrollers. It gives you a higher level APIs on top of what you have to "bare code" using only pySerial. You do not have to interface with serial data directly instead you can work with Pin class.

Comment: Oh so you are saying that it allows you to, from Python, directly take/send information from/to an Arduino pin rather than having to deal with the details? Wow, thanks, that is super useful!

Comment: Whether the baud matters depends how much data you are taking and also what response you need. at 9600 baud, each character takes 1ms-ish. If you are only transferring a few characters you aren't going to notice this. I would focus on the initialization - can you make the arduino application code you are running indicate when it is ready by e.g. turning an LED on or off, or turn it on at the first possible opportunity early in the initialization then off once initialization is complete?